# How javac detect ambiguity?

Tags: java, javac, ambiguity

How javac (java compiler) finds the errors in respect to ambiguity and generates errors in compile time itself ?

how the compiler finds that we are passing a null value before execution

```
public class Ambiguity {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ambiguity test = new Ambiguity();
    test.overloadedMethod(null);               

}

void overloadedMethod(IOException e) {
    System.out.println("1");
}

void overloadedMethod(FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("2");
}

void overloadedMethod(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("3");
}

void overloadedMethod(ArithmeticException e) {
    System.out.println("4");
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how"? Do you want to know how the compiler is implemented? You can view the source code of OpenJDK's compiler on their GitHub repo, but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The point isn't that the compiler knows you're passing `null`; the point is that when you write a literal `null` in your code, the compiler doesn't know what the type of that `null` is, so it doesn't know which overload to call.

This, for example, would compile just fine:

```
    FileNotFoundException e = null;
    test.overloadedMethod(e);
```

You can also use an explicit cast to indicate which type you intended:

```
    test.overloadedMethod((FileNotFoundException) null);
```

Keep in mind that overloading is resolved at *compile time*. So if you're calling `test.overloadedMethod(e)` where `e` is *statically* of type `Exception`, it will always call `overloadedMethod(Exception)` even if `e` is a `FileNotFoundException` at *runtime*.